# Which software is required to create android sprites?

Tags: android, sprite, game-development

I am completely new to android game programming. I really dont have any idea how can we create animated sprites. I have seen this guy using that amazing application RUBE to create a game character http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bBIXpu-D_Zo can we do that stuff in android too ?

Even if we can how can we load such massing character to our andorid project. I accept i am noob at this but i have great interest in game development, please help me with detailed answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure libgdx and AndEngine both have Sprite libraries for doing this.

Comment: @ConnorTumbleson I mean a dedicated program so that we can load these sprites into our game, i will take that course online or any institution just for game character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you'll need is a sprite sheet. A series of images on the same bitmap laid out in a grid. For example you would have 8 different sprites of the same character, 1 standing still., 1 left foot forward, 1 right foot forward and jumping and again facing the opposite direction.

When you draw the sprite set the coordinates to be drawn and on button presses change the variables controlling the coordinates.

A good tutorial is here http://warriormill.com/2009/10/adroid-game-development-part-1-gameloop-sprites/

and a sprite sheet maker can be found here http://www.codeandweb.com/sprite-sheet-maker

Hope this helps!